# How to use xargs on an array of files

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I want to store the find command output in a variable and use it many times as find command consumes time.

```
abc=`find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "abc.txt"`

echo "${abc[*]}" | xargs grep -l "somestring1"
echo "${abc[*]}" | xargs grep -l "somestring2"
echo "${abc[*]}" | xargs grep -l "somestring3"
```

But it only greps on the first element of array abc.

Comment: But `abc` is not an array…

Comment: You might want to check `-exec` option for `find` and `-E` option for `grep`; unless you want separate results for above 3 pipelines...

Comment: As mentioned by @gniourf_gniourf - abc is not an array. Edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using nonstandard `-maxdepth`, I'm assuming non-standard `find` that handles the `-print0` predicate, so as to safely build an *array*:

```
abc=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    abc+=( "$f" )
done < <(find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "abc.txt" -print0)
```

There you have an *array* `abc`.

Now, you can safely pass the array `abc` as arguments to `grep`:

```
grep -l "somestring1" "${abc[@]}"
grep -l "somestring2" "${abc[@]}"
grep -l "somestring3" "${abc[@]}"
```

**Note 1.** In your code, `abc` is not an array.

**Note 2.** I have no idea why you say your code doesn't work… it should work (provided you have nice filenames without spaces and quotes); maybe you're not showing the full code?